# Setting Isolation level in ruby v 2.1.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, isolation-level, transaction-isolation

I have been struggling with putting a record level lock on my table, to avoid any dirty reads and race condition while updating the record.
I am using ruby 2.1.3 and rails version 3.2.13. I tried using the command:

```
Account.connection.execute("SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE")
```

and tested by putting sleep, but 2 processes trying to update the same record read the old value and the final data is wrong. For example: if my old value is 100, both processes read 100 and then update, 100+x and 100+y and thus,the data is getting corrupted.

I am using mySQL database. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solution worked for me (slight modification of dimakura's answer):

1. When I used find() for active record query:

   ```
   acc = Account.lock.find(id)
   acc.balance += 100
   acc.save!
   ```
2. When I used where() for active record query:

   ```
   acc = Account.where(:acc_code => acc_code).first
   acc.with_lock do
    acc.balance += 100
    acc.save!
   end
   ```

Answer (score 2):

There are two locking mechanisms supported in Rails: [optimistic](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Optimistic.html) and [pessimistic](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Pessimistic.html).

Updating account balance, using pessimistic locking, should look like this:

```
acc = Account.find(id)
acc.with_lock do
  acc.balance += 100
  acc.save!
end
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked for 1 case. Still working on other cases. Will update once that is done.

Comment: I also need to know that if the variable acc is blank (i.e. no active record present, will acc.with_lock raise some exception or will it execute the block? Can you help out in that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If `acc` is `nil` (blank) it will raise `method not defined` exception. You need to check this before starting block.